# How to compute range of quartile range

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, percentile

Given a table, I need to compute the interquartile range for 25% and 75% quartile--it should be just one output the difference.

Note: 'gini' is just a column in my table rdata; I am not going to input my data here as the data is very long but I just need to figure out how to output the difference through percentile_disc/cont.

```
select percentile_disc(0.75)-percentile_disc(0.25) within group (order by gini) from rdata;
```

output error:

```
LINE 1: select percentile_disc(0.75)-percentile_disc(0.25) within gr...
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts..
```

I tried to cast percentile_disc::numeric but that gives me an error too.

Comment: you need the function percentile_disc as the error message says clearly

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql?

Comment: @jarlh: from the error message, this is Postgres. I removed the MySQL tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `within group` has to be specified for each `percentile_disc()`

```
select percentile_disc(0.75) within group (order by gini) - 
          percentile_disc(0.25) within group (order by gini)
  from rdata;
```

Comment: than you, does postgres library specify this? why is within group specified for each one

Comment: @Isabelle The documents do, but it may not be explicit enough.  The `percentile_dist()` aggregation function does not stand by itself.  It requires a `within group (order by <some column>)` following it in order for the invocation to work.